# Javascript to open URL within a new Tab (instead of a window)

Tags: javascript, tabs, window.open

Hey guys. There are a few entries here requiring solutions to do the opposite of this, and others vaguely related. In one of them, the poster asked how to do this on Mozilla Firefox. Actually though, firefox will *always* open the URL in a new tab when window.open() is called, unless you set the window's size within its parameters.

So Mozilla and Chrome do what I want by default. The question is: how do I get Internet Explorer to open the URL I want within a new tab, as opposed to doing it in a new window?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually Firefox will open a new tab or window depending on the user's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to open the link with `target="_blank"`. As you said, Firefox and Chrome will open a new tab.

Regarding IE - the behavior is up to browser preferences. By default (in IE7+ obviously) I believe the behavior is defined as open new tab. If the user decided the behavior should be a new window, there's only so much you can do about it.

Comment: Yuval is correct, that's is a browser user defined preference.

Comment: The only way I know is via extensions or Greasemonkey scripts http://browservulsel.blogspot.com/2006/03/single-left-click-tab-opener-user.html

Comment: Also take a look to this thead http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19843