# Is there a way to force an "onclick" new window to open in a tab?

Tags: javascript, css, target, window.open

Related but dormant: [Javascript to open URL within a new Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272176/javascript-to-open-url-within-a-new-tab-instead-of-a-window) and a number of others...

I have a client who insists that a particular link needs to open in a new tab, rather than a window. It's being generated by the "onclick" event of a form submission button, called by a jquery function in the php document that looks like this:

```
function newTabLink($element,$url) {        

    ?><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready( function() {
            jQuery('<?php echo $element; ?>').click( function() {
                window.open( "<?php echo $url; ?>",'_blank' );
                } );
            } );
            //]]></script><?php     
}
```

I also have a css declaration in my stylesheet which tries to force new windows into tabs rather than new windows:

```
* { target-new: tab !important; }
```

The css **target-new** property seems to work in IE9, forcing the popup into a tab. FF and Chrome/Safari both default to tabbed browsing, even without that property set. But how can I force IE8 and 7 to open this particular link in a tab?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm willing to try convoluted solutions (i.e. setting the form action to a new window, then returning to the original window for further logic/processing of the form)... Not expecting a linear answer to my question, but a creative workaround...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reliably do that. As you note, Firefox and the WebKit browsers can be configured to open new windows however the user wants. I **hope** that IE9 can be configured to override the behavior of that "style". (*edit* — that appears to be a draft CSS3 thing - I hope personally that it dies in committee.)

Comment: CSS3 includes a number of properties that override the default behavior of browsers: "target-new" (tab/window) and "target-position" (front/back). Yeah, user settings take precedence, but I'm not concerned with overriding those, just the browser's default behavior...

Comment: Well then that's the best thing to do; I've never seen any APIs that control that behavior. I know that Safari is extremely tight with what it'll let page code do as far as affecting desktop activity, and this seems like it falls into that category (as opposed to "intra-page" stuff).

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer. You can't do this, and really, you shouldn't want to. Good enough.